# Bayonetta: change graphics settings error

Tags: technical-issues, pc, bayonetta

I just bought Bayonetta for PC and whenever I attempt to change the graphics settings the game freezes and I get an error window stating:

> Failed to write save data

When I click ok on the error window, it disappears and the game unfreezes. Apparently the graphics settings were changed but if I restart the game these settings go back to default.

This just seems to happen to these specific settings. I changed the sound settings previously and I had no problem whatsoever.

Has anyone encountered this problem and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the game wasn't at fault.

My anti-virus Bitdefender was blocking the application from writing on disk.
I just had to add Bayonetta as a trustworthy application on Bitdefender and it started to work!

Comment: Toy can mark your answer accepted by clicking the check mark ;)